# Absolute and relative pathname --> Environment variables in the stack

Tags: linux, stack, environment-variables

I have a question that I don't know how to solve.

The issue is simple.

**1)** If I launch "/home/jc/str/stack-based_overflow" :
The BYTECODE environment variable adress in the stack is (always) : **0xbffffe2a**

**2)** If I launch "./stack-based_overflow" :
The BYTECODE environment variable adress in the stack is (always) : **0xbffffe42**

**3)** If I launch "gdb /home/jc/str/stack-based_overflow" or "gdb ./stack-based_overflow" :
The BYTECODE environment variable adress in the stack is (always) : **0xbffffe62**

How it can be possible ???

Thank you very much !!
JC!

Comment: Your `argv[]` array, which includes the path by which the program was invoked, is likely living on the top part of your stack...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that there was a environment variable "_" with the command :

```
_=/home/flo/str/envVar
_=./envVar
```

Comment: It answers ! I will valid this post in 2 days !